# Any solution for error code 1603 in SQL Server 2017 installation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-express

I installed some SQL Server Instances in 2005 and 2016 version. Now, I am trying install 2017 version, but I get the following message:

```
   === Verbose logging started: 07/09/2018  15:08:25  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Users\Soporte-07\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:810]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:810]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:810]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\Soporte-07\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:811]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:811]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:813]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:813]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:814]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:818]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\Soporte-07\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:818]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (BC:4C) [15:08:25:819]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:820]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:820]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:820]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:821]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:821]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (BC:C8) [15:08:25:821]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:822]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (1C:00) [15:08:25:823]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 07/09/2018  15:08:25 ===
```

I tried to change using the SYSTEM user but it didn't work. Any ideas?

[image: This is the error message]

Comment: I don't see (or find via a search) the word *Error* anywhere in this post except in your title.  Where do you see an error occurring exactly?

Comment: It appears several times in the log file. It occurs during the SQL instance instalation.

Comment: The error description in the image you just added says a dependency was not met. Did you visit the link in the Error Details (not the one below) for assistance troubleshooting the issue? What did that site tell you to do, what did you do as a result of that information, and what were the results of that effort?

Comment: Unfortunately, the link takes me nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. My error was I installed SQL Management Studio 17.9 before when I should had installed first the SQL instance . So uninstalling SQL Management Studio and all their related componets allowed me to install SQL Server 2017 whithout problems.

Thanks anyway for your answers, Ken.